# Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

When I run  the code below

```
  $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'recipe' => $this->input->post('recipe'),
                'category_id' => $category_id,
                'recipe_elements' => $this->input->post('recipe_elements'),
                'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
                'video' => $this->input->post('video'),
                'img' => $img_name,
                'vote' => $this->input->post('oy')
            );

            $this->db->insert('recipes',$data);
```

I get this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: 4096
>   Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
>   Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php
>   Line Number: 552
>   Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '

I already tried to change the input values but still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to convert an `object` to a `string`.Please make sure `$category_id` and `$img_name` is not an `object`.

Take a look here this may help you. [Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607550/object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string?rq=1)

You can sse:`$this->db->last_query();` which Returns the last query that was run (the query string, not the result). From where you can see easily your query string which also help you findout actual error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems I made a mistake on definening the $category_id variable.