# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string - laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am following [this documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export)

to implement export to Excel in my laravel 4 project.

So am trying to generate excel file from array like this:

```
//$results is taken with db query

$data = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
   $result->filed1 = 'some modification';
   $result->filed2 = 'some modification2';
   $data[] = $result;
}
Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) use($data) {

$excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use($data) {

    $sheet->fromArray($data);

      });

})->export('xls');
```

But this raises exception:

```
  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

What am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE:

Tried this:

```
$data = get_object_vars($data);
```

which results in:

```
get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given
```

This:

```
$data = (array)$data;
```

Results in the initial error.

Comment: I think you missed something with your configuration. Double check your `app/config.php` file for Service Provider and aliases.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`$data` is indeed an array, but it's made up of objects.

Convert its content to array before creating it:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
   $result->filed1 = 'some modification';
   $result->filed2 = 'some modification2';
   $data[] = (array)$result;  
   #or first convert it and then change its properties using 
   #an array syntax, it's up to you
}
Excel::create(....
```

Answer (score 61):

Try this simple in one line of code:-

```
$data= json_decode( json_encode($data), true);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This should be right answer, due to its simplicity this one must be right answer.
Worked for me. Thanks alot.

Comment: I think this works better as it converts any nested objects to arrays as well.

Answer (score 10):

You might need to change your object to an array first. I dont know what `export` does, but I assume its expecting an array.

You can either use

[get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Or if its a simple object, you can just typecast it.

`$arr =  (array) $Object;`

Comment: Can you var_dump($data) and its an object or an array? And you havent mentioned which line produces the error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Collection of stdClass objects, you could try with this:

```
$data = $data->map(function ($item){
            return get_object_vars($item);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was recieving the same error when I was tring to call an object element by using another objects return value like;

```
$this->array1 = a json table which returns country codes of the ip
$this->array2 = a json table which returns languages of the country codes

$this->array2->$this->array1->country;// Error line
```

The above code was throwing the error and I tried many ways to fix it like; calling this part `$this->array1->country` in another function as return value, `(string)`, taking it into quotations etc. I couldn't even find the solution on the web then i realised that the solution was very simple. All you have to do it wrap it with curly brackets and that allows you to target an object with another object's element value. like;

```
$this->array1 = a json table which returns country codes of the ip
$this->array2 = a json table which returns languages of the country codes

$this->array2->{$this->array1->country};
```

If anyone facing the same and couldn't find the answer, I hope this can help because i spend a night for this simple solution =)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy all you need to do is something like this Grab your contents like this

```
  $result->get(filed1) = 'some modification';
  $result->get(filed2) = 'some modification2';
```

Answer (score 0):

`toArrayDeep` worked for me

```
$data = $query->get()->toArrayDeep();
```