# How to convert object class into string

Tags: php, string, object, ssh, ssh2-exec

How can I convert the following object into string:

```
$ssh->exec('tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv');
```

So I can parse the string as the first parameter in strripos():

```
if($idx = strripos($ssh,','))//Get the last index of ',' substring 
{
$ErrorCode = substr($ssh,$idx + 1,(strlen($ssh) - $idx) - 1); //using the found index, get the error code using substring
echo " " .$Playlist.ReturnError($ErrorCode); //The ReturnError function just replaces the error code with a custom error
}
```

As currently when I run my script I get the following error message:

```
strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string
```

I've seen similar questions including this one [Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607550/object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string) , however I still can't seem to come up with a solution.

Comment: What is the type of `$ssh`? You should `strripos()` on the value returned by `$ssh->exec()`, not on `$ssh`.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve, I was thinking of taking the output from the `$ssh` variable (which is type object) into string and then parsing that string into `strripos()`

Comment: @axiac Could be, guess we'll need to see if OP replies.

Comment: @chris85 the [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function is a global function, the code posted in the question uses a method of some class (that probably wraps the functions provided by the [`SSH2`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) PHP extension). They cannot be the same.

Comment: @axiac I agree the `strripos($ssh` won't work because `$ssh` is not a string so it won't work. Without the `$ssh` definition though hard to say, outside of just saying to assign the return. Assigning the return won't work if the return is an object, or even NULL. I guess i'll remove that comment until what their `exec` does is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with this line of code:

```
if($idx = strripos($ssh,','))
```

1. `$ssh` is an instance of some class. You use it above as `$ssh->exec(...)`. You should check the value it returns (probably a string) and `strripos()` on it, not on `$ssh`.
2. [`strripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) returns `FALSE` if it cannot find the substring or a number (that can be `0`) when it founds it. But in boolean context, `0` is the same as `false`. This means this code cannot tell apart the cases when the comma (`,`) is found as the first character of the string or it is not found at all.

Assuming `$ssh->exec()` returns the output of the remote command as string, the correct way to write this code is:

```
$output = $ssh->exec('tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv');

$idx = strrpos($output, ',');        //Get the last index of ',' substring 
if ($idx !== FALSE) {
    // The value after the last comma is the error code
    $ErrorCode = substr($output, $idx + 1);
    echo ' ', $Playlist, ReturnError($ErrorCode);
} else {
   // Do something else when it doesn't contain a comma
}
```

There is no need to use [`strripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php). It performs case-insensitive comparison but you are searching for a character that is not a letter, consequently the case-sensitivity doesn't make any sense for it.

You can use [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) instead, it produces the same result and it's a little bit faster than `strripos()`.

---

#### An alternative way

An alternative way to get the same outcome is to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split `$output` in pieces (separated by comma) and get the last piece (using [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) or [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)) as the error code:

```
$output = $ssh->exec('tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv');

$pieces = explode(',', $output);
if (count($pieces) > 1) {
    $ErrorCode = (int)end($pieces);
    echo ' ', $Playlist, ReturnError($ErrorCode);
} else {
   // Do something else when it doesn't contain a comma
}
```

This is not necessarily a better way to do it. It is, however, more readable and more idiomatic to PHP (the code that uses `strrpos()` and `substr()` resembles more the C code).

Comment: Assigning the output  from `exec` to a variable such as `$output` is what I was after, so I can now parse this into `strripos()`, but your `strripos()` function isn't outputting anything after the last ',' . I understand this isn't related to my original question but if you're able to help I can upload the relevant code as I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong..

Comment: Nonetheless, I will still accept your answer as it's the solution to the original question.

Comment: I don't get you. If `$idx` is not `FALSE` then `substr($output, $idx + 1)` returns the piece of `$output` that starts after the last comma. It returns an empty string, of course, if the comma is the last character in `$output`.

Comment: This is what my `$output` returns: `2018-03-22 12:43:21,NM_Test.h264,-2` .. there'll always be a number present after the last comma, I have a switch case `function ReturnError(res)` so I'm trying to get my `strripos()` function to look at the last output after the ',' and match it with a case inside my `ReturnError(res)` function.

Comment: The value of `$output` probably ends with a new line. You should convert the error code to integer. Check it here: https://3v4l.org/ek5tv

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your support.