# Why i got this error Object of class stdClass?

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

Im decoding a json string, with this code:

```
$response = (string) file_get_contents($api);
$response = json_decode($response);
echo $response->MySomeKey;
```

I got this error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

Why i got this error, and how i can fix it simply?

Comment: `MySomeKey` is also an object of type `stdClass `. Try a `var_dump` instead a `echo`, you will see what it looks.

Comment: i'm still pretty new to this, but i usually get that error when i try and echo out an array. what do you get if you `print_r($response);` instead of echo?

Comment: With var_dump, not work's, echo $response->var_dump(result), i put wrong var_dump?

Comment: Sam.92, it means im calling a not existent key inside the json $response?

Comment: Ugo T., I need your help :(

Comment: Sam.92 HELP ME PLS!!

Comment: We can't really help further without you doing a `print_r($response)` as Sam said and editing you post to add that content in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607550/object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Comment: Thank you Chris White, but all is right!, and the solution found...

Comment: And miken32, thanks by add that post...

Comment: N.B. you're correct, `echo $response->var_dump(result)` is completely wrong. The $response object doesn't have a method called var_dump. var_dump is a built-in function in PHP used for debugging, to write out the whole contents of a variable. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php . In your case `var_dump($response);` would be what you would have needed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution, my problem was i try to print using echo of a key(MySomeKey) json(object), i have to print  using echo the value of the key not the key(object):

```
$response = (string) file_get_contents($api);
$response = json_decode($response);
echo $response->MySomeKey->MyKeyValue;
```

result:

```
"MyValueOfSomeKey"
```

Thanks to [Ugo T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3930220/ugo-t) and [Sam.92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7596471/sam-92), I found the bug and i build this solution.